# How to stack marginal increase/decrease? Stacked bar plot -R

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question seems fairly simple, but I wasn't able to find another post that answers it (apologies if I've missed it though).

I have a variable with three factors (a value for each month). The data looks like the below:

```
id  variable value
AZ   Feb-20  1085
AZ   Mar-20     1
AZ   Apr-20    61
CO   Feb-20     6
CO   Mar-20   192
FO   Apr-20     2
```

I want to stack the data, such that I have a bar for February, and then the marginal increases for March, and April stacked on top.

Right now, the values for each month are stacked on top of each other.

```
ggplot(df3, aes(x = id, y = value, fill=factor(variable, levels=c("Apr-20","Mar-20", "Feb-20")))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

How do I stack the increases from February? Is there a way to modify a stacked bar plot or do I need to try another method?

**EDIT**

After thinking on this, I believe the best solution is overlapping bars. But higher bars cover smaller bars. Changing the transparency isn't very useful with three factors. Maybe there is a way to reorder so that the smaller bars are in the forefront?

```
ggplot(df2) +geom_bar(aes(x = id, y = `Feb-20`), position = "identity",stat="identity", fill = 'green') +
  geom_bar(aes(x = id, y = `Mar-20`), position = "identity", stat="identity",fill = 'navy') +
  geom_bar(aes(x = id, y = `Apr-20`), position = "identity", stat="identity", fill = 'red')
```

[image]

**Second Edit**
Apologies, this is my fault for being unclear. Prior, I wanted to avoid the cumulative summing that occurs with stacked barplots, and asked that each additional month be added as a marginal increase.

Now, though, as overlapping barplots, it is not necessary for the bars to display change. The problem with the overlapping bar charts is just that the data is obscured for bars with a shorter height.

This plot still plots marginal change. I'm looking for something like plot 2 in this post, but where all of the data is visible.

[image]

**EDIT 3**

Maybe this is a better way to explain:

Take the example of 'WA' in the first plot. For Feb, the data point was `338`, for March, the data point was `318`, and for April, the data point was `2270`. A stacked bar plot adds these on top of each other, cumulatively.

However, the bar that I want for 'WA' should really show `338` for February, then a drop of `20` for March. And finally, an addition of `1952` for April.

This is why I had used the language of a marginal increase/decrease for a stacked barplot. I had also tried an overlapping barplot, but all of the data is not visible, and longer bars cover shorter bars.

Comment: Do you want to order the bars

Comment: Yes, so that for each id, the order from the baseline to top (ie, from left to right) is Feb-20, Mar-20, Apr-20.

Comment: How would you show a marginal decrease? Do you want the bars to be stacked or not? You appear to be saying both.

Comment: Do you need `df1 %>% arrange(id, as.yearmon(variable, '%b-%y')) %>% mutate(variable = factor(variable, levels = unique(variable))) %>%  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = value, fill = variable)) +  geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: @akrun Thank you, this is closer to what I'd imagined, but after seeing the plot, I realized that an overlapping bar chart is closer to what I need. Still, higher bars are covering data from smaller bars. Changing the alpha hasn't helped with three factors. Updated the question

Comment: @YuNa do you consider that as an answer

Comment: @akrun Thank you for your help, if you post it as a solution, I'm happy to accept. If you have any advice as to how to reorder the bars so the smallest are visible too, I'd appreciate it. But I will still accept the current comment

Comment: @YuNa when you say, the smallest are visible, you meant to scale it?

Comment: Or you meant you want to have all the bars even if some levels are absent

Comment: @akrun I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by scaling, but what I mean is that no data should be covered. In the second plot I posted, red bars are covering navy and green bars. I want those smaller navy and green bars to be in the forefront. In essence, no data should be covered. I thought that could occur by moving longer bars to the back

Comment: DO you need `df1 %>% complete(id, variable, fill =list(value = 0)) %>% arrange(id, as.yearmon(variable, '%b-%y')) %>% mutate(variable = factor(variable, levels = unique(variable))) %>%  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip()`

Comment: @YuNA supppose you have a label column, would `+ geom_text_repel(size = 4, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + coord_flip()` works for you

Comment: @YuNA If I look at the third bar for TX, the one at the tip with red is not clear

Comment: @akrun I'd updated the post earlier, but hadn't gotten a chance to comment --- the third plot is the syntax provided in your comment using ```complete```. I'm looking for something like plot 2, but where all the data is visible. Let me know if its still unclear, and I will try to elaborate!

Comment: there is a constraint here because we are creating the factor based on the order of yearmonth

Comment: @YuNa i updated based on the code you showed in plot #2

Comment: @akrun Sorry for this headache, but the updated code produces basically plot 2 again. If we remove the constraint where the order matters, would all of the bars be visible?

Comment: @YuNa May be my earlier suggestion to `arrange` by the 'value' and then create the `factor` for `variable i.e. `df %>% arrange(id, desc(value)) %>% mutate(variable = factor(variable, levels = unique(variable))) %>%  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: Ah, I tried that, but it was the same issue as in my original plot. I clarified a bit in my third edit in the post. I'm sorry this is a pain. If this still isn't clear, I will make a separate post!

Comment: @YuNa thanks, can you make it as a separate post so that it becomes more clear

Comment: Posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62078386/reorder-overlaid-bars-in-plot-so-longer-bars-are-in-back-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `arrange` based on converting the column to `yearmon` class (from `zoo`), then convert to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` elements (or do a `match` and convert)

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)
df1 %>%
    arrange(id, as.yearmon(variable, '%b-%y')) %>% 
    mutate(variable = factor(variable, levels = unique(variable))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = id, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

---

If we wanted to automate the second plot

```
library(tidyr)


df2 <- df1 %>% 
       pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = value)


p <- ggplot(df2)

colrs <- c('green', 'navy', 'red')
nm1 <- names(df2)[-1]
for(i in seq_along(nm1)) p <- p + 
          geom_bar(aes(x = id, y = !! rlang::sym(nm1[i])), 
          position = 'identity', stat = 'identity', fill = colrs[i])
```