# Reorder Overlaid Bars in Plot so Longer Bars are in back -R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a barplot that I want to overlay. The issue is that longer bars are covering shorter bars. There's a function in excel that allows for longer bars to be pushed to the back, and shorter bars brought to the forefront. How can I do that in R?

My code is below:

```
ggplot(df2) +geom_bar(aes(x = id, y = `Feb-20`), position = "identity",stat="identity", fill = 'green') +
  geom_bar(aes(x = id, y = `Mar-20`), position = "identity", stat="identity",fill = 'navy') +
  geom_bar(aes(x = id, y = `Apr-20`), position = "identity", stat="identity", fill = 'red')
```

And produces this chart:

[image]

Now, I've seen some solutions to this issue by changing the transparency. Since I have three factors, changing the alpha hasn't been very clear:

[image]

How can I change the overlay ordering of the bars, so longer bars are in the back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you switch to `geom_col` if you are going to be plotting bars, but supplying `x=` and `y=` aesthetics.  [See here for the documentation explanation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html).  With that being said, it will work either way.  Basically:

- **Tidy Data**: I cannot confirm, but it seems that your dataset `df2` is not organized following [Tidy Data Principles](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html), which makes things much easier with `ggplot2` and many other methods of data analysis.  Instead of having your y values split among `df2$Mar-20` and `df2$Apr-20`, you should have a column for the category (let's call it `df2$date`) and a column for the actual value `df2$y`.  You would then have one call to `geom_bar` giving `aes(x=id, y=y)`.  You can do this via `dplyr::gather()` or `melt` from the `reshape2` package.
- **Arrange Data:** Outside of any other influence (such as ordering of the levels of a factor), the plotting function in `ggplot2` will plot data according to the arrangement of the actual dataframe for the `x=` and `y=` aesthetic.  This means if you order the data beforehand on a particular, non-factor value, this will dictate the order in which `ggplot2` will plot.  So, you should order the plot based on descending `df2$y` prior to plotting to have the largest bars plotted first and smallest last, which means the smallest will be in front.

Here's a complete example with dummy data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  x=rep(LETTERS[1:10],3),
  y=sample(1:100,30,replace=TRUE),
  id=c(rep('Group1',10),rep('Group2',10),rep('Group3',10))
)

df %>%
arrange(-y) %>%
ggplot(aes(x,y)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=id),stat='identity',position=position_identity())
```

[image]

Try that `ggplot()` function without the `arrange()` function and you'll see the effect is what you're looking to do.

Comment: Great explanation and solution! Worked like a charm